# Division property of invariant factors when computing rational canonical forms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In general if $k[x]$ is a PID and $V$ is a vector space over $k$ with linear transformation $T$ and $$V \cong k[x]/(f_1(x))\oplus \cdots \oplus k[x]/(f_n(x))$$
is the associated $k[x]$ module,for some monic polynomials $f_i(x)$, in order to compute the rational canonic must we have that $$f_1(x)|\cdots|f_n(x)$$
? If $V$ is in the form without the polynomial division, are the polynomials $f_i(x)$ even considered invariant factors?

For example if I want to determine all possible similarity classes of $n \times n$ matrices over a certain field given a certain condition, and I want to use rational canonical forms to do this, and I can write the $k[x]$ module as a direct sum of cylics explicitly, must I have the invariant factors dividing eachother? That is if I want to construct the matrix using companion blocks of each invariant factor?

Also say $V$ is in the direct sum form above but the polynomials $f_i(x)$ do not divide eachother. Suppose we try and compute rational canonical forms where blocks are companion matrices of each of the $f_i(x)$'s. Would this matrix then be similar to "the" rational canonical form of the matrix?